# Math.floor возвращяет NAn

Tags: javascript

Есть код:

```
var lvl_user = '21,711';
lvl_user = Math.floor(lvl_user);
alert(lvl_user);
```

Возвращает NaN, что не так.

Answer (score 1):

а не так то, что lvl_user - это строка

Вам нужно либо эту строку к числу.
Конкретно в вашем случае этот код даст нужный эффект:

```
var lvl_user = '21,711';
lvl_user = parseInt(lvl_user);
alert(lvl_user);
```

либо, если необходимо по какой-либо причине именно Math.floor использовать, строку привести к числу можно так:

```
lvl_user = parseFloat(lvl_user.replace(',','.'))
```

Comment: кто бы спорил. Чуть ниже я приводила ссылку на jsfiddle, где Math.floor применяется к строке, и всё работает.
Но тут речь о том, что строка с запятой может быть расценена только как строка, числом ей не быть без применения спецсредств в виде parseint или parseFloat

Comment: @Елена Левина свой комментарий я удалил -- дурноватый он. Но аллергия на слаботипизированные языки, чувствую, отпустит не скоро. Надо же додуматься назначить "+" операцией конкатенации строк, и <строка> + <число> -- конкатенация строки и строкового представления числа. Поведение перла в такой ситуации и то кажется более естественным. Звери, не люди.

Answer (score 0):

Разделителем целого числа, должна быть не запятая, а точка

```
var lvl_user = "21.711";
lvl_user = Math.floor(lvl_user);
alert(lvl_user);
```

...и цифровые значения можно задавать без кавычек

Comment: var lvl_user = "21,711";
lvl_user = lvl_user.replace(',', '.');
lvl_user = Math.floor(lvl_user);
alert(lvl_user);
Увы всё равно не работает.

Comment: точно не работает?
http://jsfiddle.net/T89Hr/ - это копипаста приведённого вами кода.

Comment: у вас где-то в самом коде ошибка, именно ваша строчка 100% рабочая

Comment: По идее, неправильно пытаться угадать десятичный разделитель: это может быть не только точка/запятая, а ещё куча всего, особенно в восточно-азиатских языках.